# adding images to an HTML Canvas Generated by C#

Tags: c#, html, wpf

Hello so I have an interesting question for everyone.  I have a WPF application that generates an html preview of a report based on Database data and user input.  My currently dilemma is that I have a HTML canvas that is created by C# as follows:

```
Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
myCanvas.Name = "cvsMyCanvas";
myCanvas.width = userDefinedByTtextBox;
myCanvas.height = userDefinedByTtextBox;
myCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed //Don't show the canvas just yet
```

My question is how do I get an image that I have saved locally to the computer on the canvas in a specific position. (i.e. A HTML Image tag object that is generated by C# and use the move to functionality)

(This is a rough example of how I think it should work but this is what I need the help on)
Example:

```
string htmlImage = "<img id=\"myImage\" src=\"C:\\Temp\\img.png\">";
htmlImage.moveTo(x,y);
```

...again the above code is an example of what it is I am trying to do. If anyone could help me out that would be great!  Also if I did not provide enough information please let me know and I will let provide it.

There seems to be some confusion on what it is I am trying to do, it is most likely my fault do to lack of explanation so allow me to elaborate more.  I have images saved in a folder in my temp directory I.  I am running a WPF application that has a WebBrowser control that I am using to display HTML.  The HTML that is used in that WebBrowser is created in the C# code behind.  I am trying to create a canvas that is displayed in the WebBrowser with the images that I have saved in my temp folder.  The code I have provided above apparently will not work for what I am trying to accomplish because there is no way to create a canvas in C# and use it in HTML. Let me know if this helps shed some light on this predicament or if even more explanation is required.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, since creating a WPF Canvas and adding an Image object is completely useless for generating HTML. You would simply have to create proper HTML text. A WPF Canvas won't do that for you and there is no way (i know of) that converts WPF objects to HTML text.

Comment: I see, thanks for your suggestion regardless Clemens and sorry to have wasted your time.  I should have been a little bit more descriptive of what my problem was in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate HTML5 code from your C#, the HTML code to generate should look like that:

```
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = <your path>;
    image.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(image, x, y, w, y);
        }
```

Then, just store it in the String or StringBuilder

Comment: so if I was to implement this in HTML that is generated by C# it would be like this?

    string getContext = "context = myCanvas.getContext('2d')";

Comment: I have provided more explanation at the bottom of my question, if you could take a look at that and let me know if you think this is still the correct approach to take.

Comment: Yes, it is an approach that should work, I am doing it a lot. Just generate the code, store it in a .html file and direct your WebBrowser control to this file. I usually use a template html file which contains all necessary tags, canvas initialization etc, and insert the dynamic part into this file just to make it faster. Also less place for bugs :-)

Comment: Yet another trick that I use quiet a lot. I have an Image class in my HTML template's script, which takes care of drawing, the only thing that I really generate is a a constructor for this class, which gets image name and location as parameters.